# Populating Gridview from SQL table with different formats

Tags: sql, .net

I created a SQL table to populate various gridviews using boundfields with the following column format:
**[Line], [Indicators], [YTD], [Jan], [Feb], ..., [Dec]**
The first two columns of my table are variables, 'YTD' and the months contain the data.

I need to create a new gridview with a general format of:
**[Line], [Indicator 1], [Indicator 2], ... , [Indicator k]**
Each distinct 'indicator' needs to be shown against its corresponding 'line' where the month is, for example, Jan.  I'll query and bind the table whenever a different month is chosen to display.

The goal is to avoid creating a new SQL table, but I'm not sure if selecting the data in this format is feasible with 1 query.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? PostGre?

Comment: Microsoft SSMS.

Comment: [Dynamic pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) might help you.